# Does anyone know whats wrong with this DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm having problem with this code here, and I can't seem to find why.

```
<body>
  <h1 id="score" style="text-align:center;align:center;">
    Get Ready
  </h1>
  <div style="height:450px;width:90%;background-color:white;border:5px solid lime;border-radius:1%;margin:0px;padding:0px">
    <button onclick="clicked(1)" id="1" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px">
  </button>
    <button onclick="clicked(2)" id="2" style="background-color:white;width:32.4%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px">
  </button>
    <button onclick="clicked(3)" id="3" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px">
  </button>
    <button onclick="clicked(4)" id="4" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:31.9%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px">
    </button>
    <button onclick="clicked(5)" id="5" style="background-color:white;width:32.4%;height:31.9%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px">
    </button>
    <button onclick="clicked(6)" id="6" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:31.9%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px">
    </button>
    <button onclick="clicked(7)" id="7" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px">
    </button>
    <button onclick="clicked(8)" id="8" style="background-color:white;width:32.4%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px">
    </button>
    <button onclick="clicked(9)" id="9" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px">
    </button>

    <script>
      setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="3"; }, 3000);
      setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="2"; }, 4000);
      setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="1"; }, 5000);
      setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="GO"; game(); }, 6000);

      function game(){

        setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="No points"; gamesetup(); }, 500);

        function gamesetup(){

          var game=true;
          var score=0;
          var litNum;



            gameloop();

        }
      }

        function gameloop(){

          if(game){
            var solved=false;
          var litNum=Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
          var litNum=litNum.toString();
          document.getElementById(litNum).style.backgroundColor="#FFFF00";
        }else{

          document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="Game Over at: "+score+".";

        }

        }

        function clicked(number){

          if(number==litNum&&game){
            if(!solved){
            var score=score+1;
            var solved=true;

            }

          }else{

            var game=false;
            var solved=false;


          }
          document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="Score: "+score+".";

      }

    </script>
  </div>
</body>
```

For some reason it won't write "Score: 0." like in id score like it should. I've written in their before in this program, and that works fine. Anyone know the problem? (And how to fix it)?

Comment: What says Console? any errors?

Comment: the HTML you posted doesn't have an element with id "score". is it somewhere else on the page, and you just forgot to post it, or does it not exist at all?

Comment: whole context would be appreciated. First thing, you should declare your variables at the beginning of the function.
edit: looks like something's wrong with the scope of variables, please post whole script / jsbin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, score is elsewhere on the page, it's just an H1 with id score, and it works fine.

Comment: Variables are declared elsewhere in project, and they work fine.

Comment: @BKFighter please post your full example using the advice in the link Leon provided. pretty hard to help without being able to see all the relevant code. you say the variables are declared elsewhere, but you might have made a simple syntax error, and none of us would ever know.

Comment: I posted the entire code for the project.

Comment: WoW what confusing way to post your question. I have posted the answer for you

Comment: I initialized the variables in the very first part of the script and non score the script works but score is undefined when printed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34055283/4339170 ... you are defining them in the local scope of the function, but not in global scope, see my answer please

Comment: You don't seem to understand what people are trying to tell you. If your score, solved, game and match variable are declared and used outside of this function then you should not be declaring them again inside the function. Also, it's considered bad practice to conditionally declare variables as you did in the IF statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `litNum` is undefined:       `if (number == litNum && game) {`

You have to define all your global `var` in global space. An do not reuse `var` everytime you want to access it!!!

Here is the working code:

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="score" style="text-align:center;align:center;">
    Get Ready
  </h1>
  <div style="height:450px;width:90%;background-color:white;border:5px solid lime;border-radius:1%;margin:0px;padding:0px">
    <button onclick="clicked(1)" id="1" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px"></button>
    <button onclick="clicked(2)" id="2" style="background-color:white;width:32.4%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px"></button>
    <button onclick="clicked(3)" id="3" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px"></button>
    <button onclick="clicked(4)" id="4" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:31.9%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px"></button>
    <button onclick="clicked(5)" id="5" style="background-color:white;width:32.4%;height:31.9%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px"></button>
    <button onclick="clicked(6)" id="6" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:31.9%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px"></button>
    <button onclick="clicked(7)" id="7" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px"></button>
    <button onclick="clicked(8)" id="8" style="background-color:white;width:32.4%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px"></button>
    <button onclick="clicked(9)" id="9" style="background-color:white;width:33%;height:33%;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px"></button>

    <script>
      setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "3";}, 3000);
      setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "2";}, 4000);
      setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "1";}, 5000);
      setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "GO";game();}, 6000);

      var game;
      var score;
      var litNum;

      function game() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "No points";
          gamesetup();
        }, 500);

        function gamesetup() {
          game = true;
          score = 0;
          gameloop();
        }
      }


      function gameloop() {
        if (game) {
          solved = false;
          litNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
          litNum = litNum.toString();
          document.getElementById(litNum).style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Game Over at: " + score + ".";
        }
      }

      function clicked(number) {
        if (number == litNum && game) {
          if (!solved) {
            score = score + 1;
            solved = true;
          }
        } else {
          game = false;
          solved = false;
        }
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score + ".";
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if I didn't do a good job. Still quite a noob at JS. I understand how annoying it is, as I do this type of stuff on Scratch(.mit.edu).

Comment: Well now you got better.

Answer (score 4):

This may not solve all the issues, but it looks like solved and score should be global variables.  You should only declare them once and they should be declared outside the function.

```
    var solved = false;
    var score = 0;
    function clicked(number){
      if(number==litNum&&game){
        if(!solved){
          score=score+1;
          solved=true;
        }
      }else{
        game=false;
        solved=false;
      }
      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="Score: "+score+".";
  }
```

Use Firebug or a similar tool to step through your code and see what is happeing.